# how to change duration of Quick Info in Completion List of Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, intellisense, code-completion

When I write `new int().`, a Completion List pops up, along with Quick Info, which describes a certain member, in this case `CompareTo()`. Unfortunately, that Quick Info disappears after a certain time. Is there a way to make it disappear only when the Completion List disappears? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That Quick Info is basically a tool tip and tool tip have a fixed time till when they can be displayed. Unfortunately it can't be changed.

[image]

Comment: It would be a nice feature to add, don't you think?